# How to divide the dataframe in pandas into multiple dataframes based on the group by results?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split, group-by

```
      Date_A                Date_B        Date_C                Amount
0   09/01/2016            09/01/2016    01/01/1800           2405814.36   
1   09/01/2016            09/01/2016    09/01/2016          11347445.71   
2   09/01/2016            10/01/2016    01/01/1800           5005106.94   
3   09/01/2016            10/01/2016    09/02/2016            391679.95   
4   09/01/2016            10/01/2016    10/01/2016          15982401.76   
5   09/01/2016            11/01/2016    01/01/1800           3625649.29   
6   09/01/2016            11/01/2016    10/14/2016            200730.30   
7   09/01/2016            11/01/2016    11/01/2016           3801867.77   
8   09/01/2016            01/01/2017    01/01/2017            398961.22   
9   10/01/2016            10/01/2016    01/01/1800           1357447.92   
10  10/01/2016            10/01/2016    10/01/2016          12365703.34   
11  10/01/2016            11/01/2016    01/01/1800           2783979.14   
12  10/01/2016            11/01/2016    10/21/2016             67891.65   
13  10/01/2016            11/01/2016    11/01/2016          10863491.98   
14  10/01/2016            12/01/2016    01/01/1800           1005897.36   
15  10/01/2016            12/01/2016    12/01/2016           1757775.53   
16  10/01/2016            01/01/2017    01/01/1800            394251.89   
17  10/01/2016            01/01/2017    12/09/2016            518831.09   
18  10/01/2016            02/01/2017    02/01/2017             29021.55   
19  11/01/2016            11/01/2016    01/01/1800          16732269.88   
20  11/01/2016            11/01/2016    11/01/2016          24903566.09   
21  11/01/2016            12/01/2016    01/01/1800          19229021.72   
22  11/01/2016            12/01/2016    12/01/2016          16198633.56   
23  11/01/2016            12/01/2016    12/20/2016            119524.82   
24  11/01/2016            01/01/2017    01/01/1800           8032009.03   
25  11/01/2016            01/01/2017    01/01/2017           1407168.25   
26  11/01/2016            02/01/2017    02/01/2017            350913.09   
27  12/01/2016            12/01/2016    01/01/1800          11399137.45   
28  12/01/2016            12/01/2016    12/01/2016          10973693.60   
29  12/01/2016            12/01/2016    12/06/2016            144625.55   
30  12/01/2016            12/09/2016    12/09/2016            134749.29   
31  12/01/2016            12/16/2016    12/16/2016            325738.94   
32  12/01/2016            01/01/2017    01/01/1800          12583630.38   
33  12/01/2016            01/01/2017    01/01/2017          16438291.27   
34  12/01/2016            02/01/2017    01/01/1800           6681684.58   
35  12/01/2016            02/01/2017    02/01/2017           1367619.74   
36  01/01/2017            01/01/2017    01/01/1800           5220981.26   
37  01/01/2017            01/01/2017    01/01/2017          13408941.99   
38  01/01/2017            02/01/2017    01/01/1800           4085550.81   
39  01/01/2017            02/01/2017    02/01/2017          11957184.41   
40  01/01/2017            03/01/2017    01/01/1800            203253.80   
41  02/01/2017            02/01/2017    01/01/1800           6027172.13   
42  02/01/2017            02/01/2017    02/01/2017           6795843.54   
43  02/01/2017            03/01/2017    01/01/1800            197842.86
```

This is the original dataframe which has to be divided into 6 dataframes by performing group by on Date_A. The result should output 6 dataframes with  Date_A values being `09/01/2016`,`10/01/2016`,`11/01/2016`,`12/01/2016`,`01/01/2017` and  `02/01/2017`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for create `dictionary` of `DataFrames`:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Date_A')))
print (d['09/01/2016'])
       Date_A      Date_B      Date_C       Amount
0  09/01/2016  09/01/2016  01/01/1800   2405814.36
1  09/01/2016  09/01/2016  09/01/2016  11347445.71
2  09/01/2016  10/01/2016  01/01/1800   5005106.94
3  09/01/2016  10/01/2016  09/02/2016    391679.95
4  09/01/2016  10/01/2016  10/01/2016  15982401.76
5  09/01/2016  11/01/2016  01/01/1800   3625649.29
6  09/01/2016  11/01/2016  10/14/2016    200730.30
7  09/01/2016  11/01/2016  11/01/2016   3801867.77
8  09/01/2016  01/01/2017  01/01/2017    398961.22
```

EDIT:

For looping use `items()`:

```
for i, df in d.items():
    print (i)
    print (df)
```

Comment: That's great! The values for which group by is applied can change,  Is there any way to print all the dataframes without providing the value, say without providing  d['09/01/2016'].

Comment: Apologies. I require one more help. I need to have each of the group by result as a dataframe. That means,I need to be able to access those 6 dataframes. Could this be done ?